# How do I track incoming IP addresses on Windows 2003 web server?

Tags: windows, webserver

How do I track incoming IP addresses on Windows 2003 web server? is there a log file on the the server that I can check? I know we an achieve this using Google analytics but i was wondering if there is a way of finding it by using our own code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS writes its logs to C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles by default, and each web site will have a separate folder there called W3SVC1 etc.

You can configure logging per site in Administrative Tools, IIS under the web site properties. In addition to file logging you can set up database logging here and choose the fields included in the log.

If you want to track them in your web application itself then whichever framework you're using should have a property to return this, e.g. in ASP.NET it's [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx).